# cpan: lzma.h not found

Tags: perl, cpan

I just installed Perl on Windows 10 and I am trying to run a script, that requires Compress::Raw::Lzma package installed.

When I run

```
cpanm Compress::Raw::Lzma
```

I got following error:

```
Lzma.xs:18:19: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Lzma.o'
```

How can I miss lzma.h file when I am actually trying to install LZMA?
Before this issue, I installed `Compress::Raw::Zlib` without problems.

Anyway, when I check the debug directory `.../.cpanm/work/randomnumber/Compress-Raw-Lzma-2.085`, there is indeed `Lzma.c` file, trying to include `lzma.h` file, which is, however, not there!

What am I missing?

Comment: See the necessary prerequisites  which you'll find in the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/PMQS/Compress-Raw-Lzma-2.085/README): *"....you need to have the following installed on your system: ... A copy of liblzma.
      liblzma is part of the XZ Utils which is available at ...."*

Comment: The perl module uses the C version of the library. You must have the liblzma C library and its headers installed first.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I must have missed the README. I have tried installing the XZ Utils from sources, I followed the XZ Utils README for Windows Installation. However, the output of the "windows/build.bash" script was an archive, containing the headers. Where should these headers be placed? I tried moving them to PATH directory, but this does not help. I still encounter the "lzma.h" not found error. I am not familiar with installing developer libraries to Windows. A help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried downloading the Compress-Raw-Lzma perl installation archive and changing the `config.in` file to location of lzma header/lib, instead of `/usr/local/include` as suggested in README. I have no idea where `/usr/local/include` is on Windows, but after the change I get other errors, like `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/lib/perl5/5.8/msys/CORE/perl.h:925:27: fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: The manual installation mentioned in my last comment was done using msys, so that might trigger the `netinet` thing. Anyway, how am I supposed to change the INCLUDE and LIB path in `config.in` when I am installing it in `cmd` using `cpan Compress::Raw::Lzma` command, which triggers the error right away?